# What checks can familiars Help with?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, familiars, helping

I have a question regarding familiars gained through *Find Familiar* for non-Warlocks.

What checks can familiars use the *Help* action to help with?

It seems that the provided list of creatures have bonuses only to *Perception* and *Stealth*. Does this mean I am limited to only these creatures and that they can only help with those checks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Working Together rules specify that:

> A character can only provide help if the task is one that
>   he or she could attempt alone.

And:

> Moreover, a character can help only
>   when two or more individuals working together would
>   actually be productive. Some tasks, such as threading a
>   needle, are no easier with help.

The familiar has no special rules for this, so it can help with anything that it is capable of doing alone where help is actually useful.

Exactly which tasks suit these criteria is between you and your DM. You certainly aren't limited to only Perception and Stealth checks. In fact, it's probably impossible to help with a Stealth check, since no matter how quiet your familiar is, it won't help you be quieter.

Comment: I disagree with help not being appropriate for stealth checks in general. Having someone signal you when the guard is looking the other way would be incredibly helpful - other cases should occur to you.

Comment: "We need a distraction."  Familiar sighs inwardly, again.

Comment: Is the help action identical to the working together rules? My hunch is it is, but there seems like cases could be made otherwise. Should that be it's own question? :D

Comment: @NautArch The Working Together rules explicitly state "in combat, this requires the Help action". That said, there are 2 versions of the Help action - the ability check one and the attack roll one.

Comment: In the quote, it says "could attempt" while in the answer it says "is capable of doing". I think this is a misreading of the rules. The quote continues: "For example, trying to open a lock requires proficiency with thieves' tools, so a character who lacks that proficiency can't help another character in that task." It seems to me this section is referring to rules mechanics that would prevent an attempt. Similarly, I don't think that stealth is just "being quiet".

Comment: @NautArch [It is now](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188737/is-the-help-action-an-example-of-or-an-exception-to-working-together).